# Vertical Align images inside li Chrome Issue

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I want to vertically align images inside li, My code works fine in firefox but not in chrome. Can any body help me with this?

Here is the HTML:

```
 <div class="brands container content">
    <ul id="brandlogo">
      <li><a href="http://scrub-market.hostedbywebstore.com/Alegria/b/11442638011" class=""><img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/12MlwaGE42L.png" alt=""/></a></li>
          <li><a href="http://scrub-market.hostedbywebstore.com/Cherooke/b/11442639011" class=""><img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/12rC5bPL82L.png" alt=""/></a></li>
          <li><a href="http://scrub-market.hostedbywebstore.com/Dickies/b/11442640011" class=""><img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/220GuD5uB5L.png" alt=""/></a></li>
          <li><a href="http://scrub-market.hostedbywebstore.com/Healing-Hands-Purple-Label/b/11442641011" class=""><img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/12qBKSlxODL.png" alt=""/></a></li>
          <li><a href="http://scrub-market.hostedbywebstore.com/Heart-Soul/b/11442643011" class=""><img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/127dR7ho7TL.png" alt=""/></a></li>
          <li><a href="http://scrub-market.hostedbywebstore.com/Koi/b/11442644011" class=""><img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/22gR5V1VEFL.png" alt=""/></a></li>
          <li><a href="http://scrub-market.hostedbywebstore.com/New-Balance/b/11442645011" class=""><img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/22Sr0En0GzL.png" alt=""/></a></li>
          <li><a href="http://scrub-market.hostedbywebstore.com/Nurse-Mate/b/11442646011" class=""><img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/12JRdD3GOjL.png" alt=""/></a></li>
          <li><a href="http://scrub-market.hostedbywebstore.com/Renova/b/11442647011" class=""><img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/22bm9-FDvpL.png" alt=""/></a></li>
          <li><a href="http://scrub-market.hostedbywebstore.com/Skechers/b/11442648011" class=""><img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/12mGjpXipJL.png" alt=""/></a></li>
          <li><a href="http://scrub-market.hostedbywebstore.com/Wonderwink/b/11442649011" class=""><img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/22D0pbgaokL.png" alt=""/></a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
#brandlogo {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 30px 0px 0px;
  position: relative;
  list-style: outside none none;
}

#brandlogo li {
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 35px;
    width: auto;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 0px;
    height: 150px;
    line-height: 150px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#brandlogo li a {
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
}
#brandlogo li a img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/wizati/1/edit?html,css,output
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's working fine in chrome 42.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***CSS***

```
#brandlogo li a {
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: inherit;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

> My using the above CSS property we just make the `a` tag to act as a table cell and occupy full `height` of its parent and `vertical-align:middle` its childern

[JS BIN DEMO](http://jsbin.com/kosagasoza/1/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 4):

Add `vertical-align: middle;` to `li` element:

```css
#brandlogo {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 30px 0px 0px;
  position: relative;
  list-style: outside none none;
}
#brandlogo li {
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 35px;
  width: auto;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 0px;
  height: 150px;
  line-height: 150px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;/*Add vertical align middle*/
}
#brandlogo li a {
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
}
#brandlogo li a img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="brands container content">
  <ul id="brandlogo">
    <li>
      <a href="http://scrub-market.hostedbywebstore.com/Alegria/b/11442638011" class="">
        <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/12MlwaGE42L.png" alt="" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="http://scrub-market.hostedbywebstore.com/Cherooke/b/11442639011" class="">
        <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/12rC5bPL82L.png" alt="" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="http://scrub-market.hostedbywebstore.com/Dickies/b/11442640011" class="">
        <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/220GuD5uB5L.png" alt="" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="http://scrub-market.hostedbywebstore.com/Healing-Hands-Purple-Label/b/11442641011" class="">
        <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/12qBKSlxODL.png" alt="" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="http://scrub-market.hostedbywebstore.com/Heart-Soul/b/11442643011" class="">
        <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/127dR7ho7TL.png" alt="" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="http://scrub-market.hostedbywebstore.com/Koi/b/11442644011" class="">
        <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/22gR5V1VEFL.png" alt="" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="http://scrub-market.hostedbywebstore.com/New-Balance/b/11442645011" class="">
        <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/22Sr0En0GzL.png" alt="" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="http://scrub-market.hostedbywebstore.com/Nurse-Mate/b/11442646011" class="">
        <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/12JRdD3GOjL.png" alt="" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="http://scrub-market.hostedbywebstore.com/Renova/b/11442647011" class="">
        <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/22bm9-FDvpL.png" alt="" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="http://scrub-market.hostedbywebstore.com/Skechers/b/11442648011" class="">
        <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/12mGjpXipJL.png" alt="" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="http://scrub-market.hostedbywebstore.com/Wonderwink/b/11442649011" class="">
        <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/22D0pbgaokL.png" alt="" />
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: i don't know. images are not vertically aligned middle for me using this solution instead are top aligned.

Comment: How it doesn't work? Probably you have different mark up than the one you provide in your OP. I test it and work both in chrome and ff.

Comment: i've copied html and css from your answer in js bin, and it didn't work.
Here is the jsbin -> http://jsbin.com/wizati/2/edit?html,css,output
and screenshot -> http://screencast.com/t/vwIbEkyq

Comment: The only change is to add `vertical-align: middle;` in this selector `#brandlogo li`.

Comment: that is what i've done. Probably its because of a different version.

Comment: It is working and in [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/kehetezuti/1/edit). Take a look. Probably js bin(that I don't use) needs entire html markup.

Comment: yes its working now on your jsbin. but neither in the system i'm working on nor if we remove html above and below body tag, including body tag.
Its annoying and confusing.

Comment: Alternative I have to connect via teamviewer to solve your issue in your system :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a `float: left;` as shown:

```
#brandlogo li {
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 35px;
  width: auto;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 0px;
  height: 150px;
  line-height: 150px;
  border-radius: 5px;
```

Comment: And you can remove display: inline-block